# Is there any Versatile and Simplest way to check if any 2 lists of String[] or String[][] ... got equaled?

Tags: java, list

What is the Versatile and Simplest way to check if these 2 lists are equaled:

```
            List<String[]> list1=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] s1={"1","2"};
            String[] s2={"3","4"};
            list1.add(s1);
            list1.add(s2);

            List<String[]> list2=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            String[] s3={"1","2"};
            String[] s4={"3","4"};
            list2.add(s3);
            list2.add(s4);
```

Some solutions on internet suggest using `Collections.sort`

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);

if(list1.equals(list2)){
    System.out.println("true");
}
else{
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

but it prints out "false"
other suggest using `containsAll`

```
if(list1.containsAll(list2)){
     System.out.println("true");
}
else{
     System.out.println("false");
}
```

but it also prints out "false"
seem the 2 above solutions only work with List but not work with `List<String[]>` or even more complicated `List<List<String[]>>`
So is there any versatile way to check whether any 2 lists are equaled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
boolean isEqual=Arrays.deepEquals(list1.toArray(), list2.toArray());
```

It is also return `true` for `List<String[][]>`, for example

```
    List<String[][]> list1 = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
    String[][] s1 = {{"1", "2"}, {"1", "2"}};
    String[][] s2 = {{"3", "4"}, {"3", "4"}};
    list1.add(s1);
    list1.add(s2);

    List<String[][]> list2 = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
    String[][] s3 = {{"1", "2"}, {"1", "2"}};
    String[][] s4 = {{"3", "4"}, {"3", "4"}};
    list2.add(s3);
    list2.add(s4);

    boolean isEqual = Arrays.deepEquals(list1.toArray(), list2.toArray());

    System.out.println(isEqual);//will  print true.
```

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29),

> - Returns true if the two specified arrays are deeply equal to one another. Unlike the equals(Object[],Object[]) method, this method is
>     appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.